# How to press a default button when by pressing an lineEdit in a WIDGET in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using QT 4.8 and C++ and I need a default push button which will be pressed when some text are input in a lineEdit and ENTER key is pressed.

According to the [QT document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) for the property "default" of pushbutton.
the behavior is only for dialogs.

> *"The default button behavior is provided only in dialogs. Buttons can always be clicked from the keyboard by pressing Spacebar when the button has focus."*

How can I have this behavior for a widget, which is a container for all my GUI components.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some sample code which you have tried out?

Comment: @Sumeet Thanks. I just set the property "default" of this button true by QtDesigner.

Answer (score 1):

You can [connect](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) the signal [`QLineEdit::returnPressed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#returnPressed) to the slot [`QAbstractButton::click()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#click).

### Method 1

from the Designer you simply can:

1. Right-click on lineEdit
2. Select "Go to slot..."

[image]

3. Choose `returnPressed()`:

[image]

4. Press ok
5. In the code view you will see the slot connected to the chosen signal
6. You can simply call the `click()` slot of a button you need:

[image]

### Method 2

You can manually connect signal of any lineEdit to a slot of any pushButton:

In Qt 4 syntax:

```
connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(returnPressed()),
            ui->anyButton, SLOT(click()));
```

In new Qt 5 syntax:

```
connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::returnPressed,
            ui->anyButton, &QPushButton::click);
```

Comment: thanks~ I tried the Method2 Qt4 syntax and now it works